# invalid message type

Tags: rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to use my own messages. I created msg file named RopEvent:

```
 int32 value
 string name
 string comment
```

I can't publish message using rostopic pub. I try to proceed

```
rostopic pub rop_client rop_client/RopEvent 14 "Test" "Test"
```

But I receive an error

```
ERROR: invalid message type: rop_client/RopEvent.
If this is a valid message type, perhaps you need to type 'rosmake rop_client'
```

I type this, it makes package correctly, but message error still pops up.
If I type rostopic list -v, I can see a string

```
* /rop_client [rop_client/RopEvent] 1 subscriber
```

'rosmsg list' shows me that my message exists, 'rosmsg show' finds message and shows it.
What's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104491/invalid-message-type/) by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-11-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [syrnick](https://answers.ros.org/users/18511/syrnick/) on 2014-05-26**:
I have the same problem. 'rosmsg show package_name/Msgname' works fine 'rostopic pub /xyz  package_name/Msgname' doesn't.

UPDATED: After I edited the package.yml and CMakeLists.txt to actually compile the messages, it worked fine.

**Comment by [pelment](https://answers.ros.org/users/5425/pelment/) on 2014-05-27**:
And which commands were missed?

**Comment by [syrnick](https://answers.ros.org/users/18511/syrnick/) on 2014-05-27**:
I think, these were the core changes and commands:

in package.xml:

```
    message_generation
    message_runtime
```

In CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  message_generation std_msgs
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  Dummy.msg
  Hit.msg
)
```

Commands from the catkin workspace:

```
catkin_make 
catkin_make install
source devel/setup.bash
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure that the compiled packages of your custom messages are in your environment when you run rostopic. That's the usual cause of this problem.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2